# jackson-databind 2.9.9.3 throws NullPointerException in AnnotatedCreatorCollector

Tags: java, jackson

Recently I upgrade jackson-databind in my application from version 2.8.7 to 2.9.9.3, it works for two weeks then we encounter NPE throwed from AnnotatedCreatorCollector._findPotentialFactories, and the issue is gone after I restart my server.

Here is the full stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedCreatorCollector._findPotentialFactories(AnnotatedCreatorCollector.java:183)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedCreatorCollector.collect(AnnotatedCreatorCollector.java:57)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedCreatorCollector.collectCreators(AnnotatedCreatorCollector.java:47)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass._creators(AnnotatedClass.java:381)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass.getFactoryMethods(AnnotatedClass.java:293)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicBeanDescription.getFactoryMethods(BasicBeanDescription.java:534)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory._addDeserializerFactoryMethods(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:852)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory._constructDefaultValueInstantiator(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:349)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.findValueInstantiator(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:269)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.createCollectionDeserializer(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:1222)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer2(DeserializerCache.java:399)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:349)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:264)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findNonContextualValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:467)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.resolve(BeanDeserializerBase.java:473)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:293)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:477)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:4191)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4010)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3005)
 at com.pactera.powerweb.util.JsonUtil.strToObj(JsonUtil.java:68)
 at com.pactera.powerweb.base.BaseService.getSessionObject(BaseService.java:313)
 at com.pactera.pcm.keyInfoApp.service.PcmKeyInfoAppService.updateKeyInfoApp(PcmKeyInfoAppService.java:233)
 at com.pactera.pcm.keyInfoApp.service.PcmKeyInfoAppService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ce1f845d.invoke(<generated>)
 at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:736)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
 at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:671)
 at com.pactera.pcm.keyInfoApp.service.PcmKeyInfoAppService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$901ee118.updateKeyInfoApp(<generated>)
 at com.alibaba.dubbo.common.bytecode.Wrapper190.invokeMethod(Wrapper190.java)
 at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.proxy.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory$1.doInvoke(JavassistProxyFactory.java:46)
 at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.proxy.AbstractProxyInvoker.invoke(AbstractProxyInvoker.java:72)
 at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.protocol.InvokerWrapper.invoke(InvokerWrapper.java:53)
 at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
 at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.protocol.ProtocolFilterWrapper$1.invoke(ProtocolFilterWrapper.java:91)
 at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.filter.TimeoutFilter.invoke(TimeoutFilter.java:42)
 at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.protocol.ProtocolFilterWrapper$1.invoke(ProtocolFilterWrapper.java:91)
 at com.alibaba.dubbo.monitor.support.MonitorFilter.invoke(MonitorFilter.java:65)
 at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.protocol.ProtocolFilterWrapper$1.invoke(ProtocolFilterWrapper.java:91)
 at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.protocol.dubbo.filter.TraceFilter.invoke(TraceFilter.java:78)
 at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.protocol.ProtocolFilterWrapper$1.invoke(ProtocolFilterWrapper.java:91)
 at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.filter.ContextFilter.invoke(ContextFilter.java:70)
 at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.protocol.ProtocolFilterWrapper$1.invoke(ProtocolFilterWrapper.java:91)
 at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.filter.GenericFilter.invoke(GenericFilter.java:132)
 at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.protocol.ProtocolFilterWrapper$1.invoke(ProtocolFilterWrapper.java:91)
 at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.filter.ClassLoaderFilter.invoke(ClassLoaderFilter.java:38)
 at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.protocol.ProtocolFilterWrapper$1.invoke(ProtocolFilterWrapper.java:91)
 at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.filter.EchoFilter.invoke(EchoFilter.java:38)
 at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.protocol.ProtocolFilterWrapper$1.invoke(ProtocolFilterWrapper.java:91)
 at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.protocol.dubbo.DubboProtocol$1.reply(DubboProtocol.java:113)
 at com.alibaba.dubbo.remoting.exchange.support.header.HeaderExchangeHandler.handleRequest(HeaderExchangeHandler.java:84)
 at com.alibaba.dubbo.remoting.exchange.support.header.HeaderExchangeHandler.received(HeaderExchangeHandler.java:170)
 at com.alibaba.dubbo.remoting.transport.DecodeHandler.received(DecodeHandler.java:52)
 at com.alibaba.dubbo.remoting.transport.dispatcher.ChannelEventRunnable.run(ChannelEventRunnable.java:82)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1157)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:627)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:809)
```

I look into the code that throws nullpointerexception,it's

```
    private List<AnnotatedMethod> _findPotentialFactories(JavaType type, Class<?> primaryMixIn)
    {
        List<Method> candidates = null;

        // First find all potentially relevant static methods
        for (Method m : ClassUtil.getClassMethods(type.getRawClass())) {
            if (!Modifier.isStatic(m.getModifiers())) {
                continue;
            }
            // all factory methods are fine:
            //int argCount = m.getParameterTypes().length;
            if (candidates == null) {
                candidates = new ArrayList<>();
            }
            candidates.add(m);
        }
```

I encounterd nullpointerexception at this line

```
 if (!Modifier.isStatic(m.getModifiers())) {
```

my code:

```
public class JsonUtil
{
...
  public static <T> T strToObj(String str, Class<T> clazz)
  {
    try
    {
      ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

      return objectMapper.readValue(str, clazz);
    } catch (JsonParseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
  }
...
}
```

Comment: would you plese share your code to see what wrong :)

Comment: sure, I have edited the question